# DCL, OpenVMS --> Error during running an Executable

Tags: openvms, dcl

I am trying to run an executable file using --> @NH1060.COM
and the NH1060.com contains the below code:

```
SET PROCESS/NAME = "Watch"
RUN R2_EXE:NH1060.EXE
```

But when am running the NH1060 Com, the com is neither giving any errors
nor the executable is running. I could see the cursor blinking in the next line.

Comment: maybe the program NJ1060.exe executes during some hours?  if you have CMKRNL privilege, do `ana/sys` so you go into SDA, and then `set proc Watch` and now you can see the open files by this process with `show proc/chan` and if the program is waiting or not with `exam @pc` you can also do, in another terminal `sh proc/cont Watch` and see if the I/O and CPU counters update regularly

Comment: by the way, post the architecture (Vax, Alpha, or Itanium) `wr sys$output f$getsyi("arch_name")` and the OpenVMS version `wr sys$output f$getsyi("version")`

Comment: Do you have the source of this program? How do you know the program is not running? You could do `CTRL T` several times when running the program, and check if the process has done a lot of I/O and used some CPU ticks between your 2 CTRL T

Comment: The doc for CTRL T http://h41379.www4.hpe.com/doc/83final/9996/9996pro_179.html

Comment: You probably need to provide more information. At least, how do you determine that the executable isn't/wasn't running? As a simple, initial trouble shooting, do a ```$ SET VERIFY``` before the ```@NH1060.COM```. This enables logging of the commands in ```NH1060.COM```. In ```NH1060.COM``` add a ```$ SHOW SYMBOL $STATUS``` after the ```RUN``` command, which shows the exit status of the image.

Comment: What it the program supposed to do? Did it ever work? What changed? Does it 'work' (whatever that means) when run interactively without the command file activating it (sys$command, sys$input logicals?). The process name suggests it is a monitor of sorts, may it is not supposed to do anything until something wrong happens. Mind you it would be nice if it at least printed "Hello World!". Is it supposed to be run as 'system' or other more priviliged username?  Good luck! Hein.

Comment: Each line of your COM file must start with '$' in order to be read properly: `$ Set process /name="watch"` and `$ run r2_exe:nh1060.exe`